# How to make advanced square using nested for-loops?

Tags: jgrasp

I have to use multiple nested loops in jGRASP to get the desired output. When I put this:

> SQUARE

I have to get this:

```
SQUARE
Q    R
U    A
A    U
R    Q
ERAUQS
```

My code so far:

```
String output="";
        output+= word;
      for (int i = 1; i < word.length()-1; i++)
      {
         output+= word.charAt(i)+"\n";
         for (int j = 0; j < word.length() - 2; j++)
         {
            output += " ";
         }
         output += (word.length() - i - 1);
      }
      StringBuffer s = new  StringBuffer(word);
      output+= s.reverse();
```

but my output is:

```
squareq
    4u
    3a
    2r
    1erauqs
```

How to fix the inner region?

It is the inner for-loop that needs help.
Should I define the `StringBuffer` before and reverse it and use `charAt()`?

I tried that and I keep getting the "cannot find symbol" error.

I am new to this site and I apologize for any inconsistencies.

Answer (score 0):

It took me only to modify 2 lines of your code, so it was pretty good.

Here is your commented solution:

```
String output="";
        output+= word+"\n";
        for (int i = 1; i < word.length()-1; i++)
        {
            output+= word.charAt(i); //removed new line
            for (int j = 0; j < word.length() - 2; j++)
            {
                output += " ";
            }
            output += word.charAt(word.length() - i - 1)+"\n"; //added charAt and new line at the end
        }
        StringBuffer s = new  StringBuffer(word);
        output+= s.reverse();
```

The result looks like expected:

```
SQUARE
Q    R
U    A
A    U
R    Q
ERAUQS
```